# Importing module from relative path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for some advice on a python issue I am having. I am a novice at python. I believe that I am relying on my programming experience from other languages to make this work and I have finally come to a stand-still. Here is the scenario, I am importing a module that relies on another module.

My driver for the program, called test.py, starts out like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.9.1\share\zorba\uris\com\nuemeta\www\modules\DDEXpedite\bindings\Python\Code and Other Files')

import QueryDDEX
```

Then in the QueryDDEX.py file I have:

```
import sys,os

temp = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath("..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\python"))

print sys.path

import zorba_api

os.chdir(temp)
```

In my head I was thinking (1)Save the current working directory, (2)Change the current working directory to the directory of the QueryDDEX.py module, (3) import the zorba_api module from a relative path because if I deploy this module to other computers they may not have the same file structure as mine, and (4) change the current working directory back to what it was initially.

Now, I have read that it is not okay to use relative paths and I have also read that it is okay. I do not see another choice because I did not write the zorba_api so I do not have too much control over it. Anyway, the output of the program is this:

```
['C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.9.1\\share\\zorba\\uris\\com\\nuemeta\\www\\modules\\DDEXpedite\\bindings\\Python\\Code and Other Files', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.9.1\\share\\zorba\\python']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Test.py", line 4, in <module>
import QueryDDEX
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.9.1\share\zorba\uris\com\nuemeta\www\modules\DDEXpedite\bindings\Python\Code and Other Files\QueryDDEX.py", line 9, in <module>
    import zorba_api
ImportError: No module named zorba_api
```

This is where things get tricky in my opinion, the zorba_api module is located at

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Zorba XQuery Processor 2.9.1\\share\\zorba\\python
```

and we can see by my debug statement that it IS in the python class path. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this scenario. You have the file `alpha.py` at `C:\projects\test\`. Then you also have a file called `beta.py` at `C:\projects\test\modules\` so to import `beta` from `alpha` you should do:

```
import modules.beta
```

Or, not very good but useful, adding the `modules` directory to your `sys.path`.

Then if you want to import modules from your `beta.py` file you will have to take care that you're not at `C:\projects\test\modules\` directory, you're in the `alpha.py` directory. So for example, if there's a third file called `gamma.py` at `modules/`, if you want to import it from `beta.py` you should use:

```
import modules.gamma
```

Because you are at the *importer file* (`alpha.py`) path, not at the *imported file* (`beta.py`) path.

Hope it helps to solve your problem!

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but maybe I don't because I still do not understand why my solution won't work in that case. I change the current working directory to __file__, so it is at the place of the module, and then I try to use a relative path from the first module to the second. It works when I use an absolute path. Lastly, what could I do to fix it? I am starting to understand why my program is not working but now I'm even more confused as to how to get it working.

Comment: When appending a new path in your `QueryDDEX.py` file you should take care that you are at the `test.py` path, so maybe the path you have provided is wrong.

Comment: Turns out I was one directory off in my relative path, adding a "/../" solved the problem. Thank you for your help, it would have taken much longer to debug without you.